# How to assign a single object to a string variable from selected spinner item

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

I want to get `countryCode` of selected country from my spinner.

here is the ArrayList

```
countryList.add(jsonObjectHoldingCountries.optString("countryName") + " - " + jsonObjectHoldingCountries.optString("countryCode"));
```

now i want to get only `countryCode` but it is returning me both `countryName` and `countryCode`

I tried it like this:

```
strNationality = (String) countrySpinner.getSelectedItem();
```

but now `strNationality` will have both country code and country name.

If you can help me it will be a great help! :)

Comment: Split the string with -

Comment: Split the returned string on " - " and read the 1st index of the array returned by the split() method

Comment: Thank you for quick response, can you guys show me the syntax i am a beginner.

Comment: `String countryCodeArray[] = strNationality.split(" - ");`
`String countryCode = countryCodeArray[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can splIt the strNationality like this:

```
  strNationality = (String) countrySpinner.getSelectedItem();
    String data[]=strNationality.split("-");
if(data.length==2)
{
    String countryName=data[0];
    String countryCode=data[1];}
```

Comment: hey i followed the same procedure... it is showing this error on activity launch

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: for solving this problem firstly you should check the length of the data .

Comment: i have edited my code with condition you may try the above code

Comment: On data.length it is saying `Method call expected`

Comment: Actually, that would be data.length instead of data.length() ,You may try again hope fully it will help out

Comment: Will you please tell me ,Is this code helpful for you or not?

Comment: Hey sorry was not online. Yup i removed () and it was working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
strNationality = (String) countrySpinner.getSelectedItem();
String [] split= strNationality.split("-");
strNationality = split[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print directly use the below code

```
   String str[] = strNationality.split("-");
   System.out.println(str[1]);
```

If you want to access this value to multiple place use the following methods

```
   String couCode = null; 
   String str[] = strNationality.split("-");
   couCode = str[1];
   System.out.println(couCode);
```

Now use **couCode** to anywhere to access based on couCode declaration ie., either globally or locally